# 12.10 Screen jitters/flickers when ever it needs to redraw graphics

Tags: drivers, graphics, settings

I just got started with ubuntu on my intel nuc (16Gb RAM, 120Gb SSD, intel HD 4000 running ubuntu 12.10). Managed to solve most of the issues that I've faced so far but there is this one I just cant get around.

My NUC is connected to my TV through HDMI. Whenever something updates on the screen, the entire screen kind of vibrates/flickers. So with a blinking cursor the entire screen is blinking. This is extremely annoying.

Anyone suffered something similar to this? If so: How did you solve it?

Best regards,

Trezzy

Comment: have you tried checking to see if it has aditional drivers to install?

Comment: The additional drivers window is empty. Should it hold something?

Comment: Well it should hold proprietary drivers  sometimes.You can try ubuntu 12.04 it is with long time support,even tough 12.10 is newest release it's not also the best.It's new, with buggs, with lot of things not ready for it yet(drivers,softwear).Example: a launcher for kubuntu just upgraded kubuntu 12.10.Until now it was for 12.04.

Comment: tried loading 12.04 of a bootable disk, still the jitters remain... =(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for taking your time to help me. I managed to find a solution and thought I would share it. The problem was with my TV. The HDMI port I use was previously used for my xbox and was set in game mode. Changed it to PC and everything works great now.

//Trezzy